# Extending to a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\beta' = \{(a,b),(p,q)\}$ be a basis for $F^2$, where $F$ is some field. Suppose that $\hat{T} (a,b) = (c,d)$ and $\hat{T}(p,q)=(r,s)$. I am trying to extend $\hat{T}$ to a linear operator on $F^2$.

Initially I thought that $T(x,y)= x \hat{T}(a,b) + y\hat{T}(p,q)$ might work, but then quickly realized that it wouldn't. However, I did notice that $T(1,0)=(c,d)$ and $T(0,1)=(r,s)$, and so I thought I could perform some change of basis to obtain a formula for $T$; but I am unsure of how to do this or whether it will work. I could use some guidance.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Bernard8 Sorry. I just edited my post to include my intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension needs to take advantage of the fact that $\{(a,b),(p,q)\}$ is a basis for the space.

For an arbitrary $v = c_1(a,b)+c_2(p,q)$ define $T(v) = c_1(c,d)+c_2(r,s)$ and this is your extension. Since every vector has a unique representation in terms of the basis vectors, this is well defined.